# Which web app can generate a mobile website from an RSS feed?

Tags: webapp-rec, rss, mobile

Which web app can generate a mobile website from an RSS feed? The RSS feed contains the full article and longitude/latitude so the articles can be marked on a map. The interface should be auto generated and leverage jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Feed2Mobile: http://feed2mobile.kaywa.com/en

Answer (score 0):

A couple of popular free choices...

- http://winksite.com
- http://mobify.me/mobile-web-design/mobify-studio/  (offers a free plan)
- http://www.mofuse.com/

You could even try google's mobifier (very basic though)
http://google.com/gwt/n